# Using the object URL pdf files are not downloading from aws s3 when using chrome. I get "Failed -Forbidden error. works in Firefox and Edge

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, amazon-s3

When using the Object Url for a file stored in AWS S3, the pdf files are not downloading from aws s3 when using chrome. I get "Failed -Forbidden error. works in Firefox and Edge

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with read/write permissions, you will need to check the S3 bucket permissions and ACL (Access control lists) modify them so you can "List" and "Read" but not "Write".

This should resolve your issue.